# Set exact time limits in Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, timing, limits

When facing data in the time domain i seem to run into problems setting the exact limits on the x-axis with matlab.

Thus i plot my data and give the xlim in matlab time and set the limits:

```
minTT = datenum(2008,10,31,17,12,00);
maxTT = datenum(2008,10,31,17,19,00);
xlim = ([minTT maxTT]);
```

Then i use the date tick option to convert the matlab timing to "real clock time".

```
datetick('x',13,'keepticks');
```

The 'keep ticks' option is still better than none and i tried with both. 
But what i get out is a plot that is going from: 17:12:28 to 17:17:58.

I have tried editing the ticks on my own as suggested from [another post at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717279/having-issues-scaling-date-time-labels-on-matlab-plot) like this:

```
ticks = get(gca, 'xtick') 
newTicks = linspace(ticks(1), ticks(end), 8);
set(gca,'Xtick', newTicks)
```

but even that doesn't work out and gives me limits from 17:12:28 to 17:17:31.

Is there any way to really force matlab to use specific times on the axis whether or not the data doesn't exactly start there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `'keeplimits'` flag to `datetick()` - it does just what it says, much like `'keepticks'`